# Page length issue in ie6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have an issue with a site at the following address:

http://www.graffiti-prevention.com.au

For some reason in ie6 the page length is really long. Everything loads fine, but the body of the page keeps showing all of the content, including the footer.

I've tried the usual fixes, but its a problem Ive never had before. It's starting to drive me mad, so I'm hoping someone will be able to help me.

Cheers

James

Comment: IE6 is dead. Just leave it alone.

Comment: I dont take anyone seriously who still uses IE6...so screw 'em!

Comment: @mingos is right -- if the site works in IE6 at all, you're doing well. Don't fret having a few layout issues in IE6; it's not worth the hassle of trying to fix them. IE6 is down to 2% market share now globally, and falling at a rate of about 0.5% per month. It might be higher in .au, but the trend will be the same; this browser is dead.

Comment: I hate ie6 as much as anyone, but unfortunately some of my b2b sites still average around 20% of monthly visits in ie6.

Comment: When the sites refuse to cooperate with ie6, the stats will change drastically :). You buy a new computer when it turns out they don't manufacture DDR memory anymore and you can't upgrade. Same should apply to the web. My company has recently finished a community portal. 10k users, many still using IE6. We don't even support IE7 though - and the world doesn't end. Users start changing browsers because of the problems they experience and everyone's happy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it might be something to do with the Fancybox plugin. Maybe try sticking in

```
body { overflow:hidden }
```

I can't actually see the page though to have a better suggestion, my IE tester keeps crashing!